# Consecutive Confirmation Alerts in IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to get two confirmations from user one after another. If the first one is cancelled, there is no need to get the second one. But if the first one is agreed on, then the second one should be shown and processed. I am using a piece of code like this

```
showConfirmation1() {
  let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'C1',
    message: "M1",
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'No',
      },
      {
        text: 'Yes',
        handler: data => {
          this.showConfirmation2(); 
        }
      }
    ]
  });

showConfirmation2() {
  let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'C2',
    message: "M2",
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'No',
      },
      {
        text: 'Yes',
        handler: data => {
          this.doYourJob(); 
        }
      }
    ]
  });
```

If user cancels the first one, everything works fine. If user accepts the first one, the second one is shown properly. However, the second one kinda freezes. Neither its No button nor its Yes button work. It does not even vanishes when you click on other areas of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Found a cleaner solution that requires less code and is easier to understand.
By returning `false` in the button `handler` you prevent the alert from closing. And the `dismiss`-function returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that gets resolved when the transition is complete. So thats where we will call the function to open the second alert.

```
showConfirmation1() {
    let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'C1',
        message: "M1",
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'No',
            },
            {
                text: 'Yes',
                handler: data => {
                    confirm.dismiss()
                    .then(() => {
                        this.showConfirmation2();
                    });

                    return false;
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    confirm.present();
}
```

**ORIGINAL:**

Make use of the `dismiss(data:any)` function on your first alert. And pass a value that indicates that it was not cancelled. In the `onDidDismiss`-function check for this value. If its there present the second alert.

```
showConfirmation1() {
    let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'C1',
        message: "M1",
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'No',
            },
            {
                text: 'Yes',
                handler: data => {
                    confirm.dismiss({ showSecond: true });
                    return false;
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    confirm.onDidDismiss(data => {
        if(data && data.showSecond){
            this.showConfirmation2();
        }
    }

    confirm.present();
}
```